# disabling magento round up

Tags: mysql, magento-1.7

I need to know how to disable magento from removing decimals in a form field of text type in my admin html backend. If I put a number in this field:

```
$fieldset->addField('radiorate', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('radiosupplier')->__('Single Radio Rate'),                    
      'name'      => 'radiorate',
  ));
```

like 523.42 after saving I get 523.00. I tried to modify my db settings for this field and set the type from integer to decimal 10,2 but then I get 523.00

How can I prevent this?

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in saveAction() 
before save statement

```
$value = number_format($value, 2);
```

or

```
 $value = number_format(523.42, 2);
```

for example you want to change **price** field which contain **decimal** value

```
$post['price']= number_format($post['price'], 2);
$model->setData($post);
```

hope this will help you